# How to refresh Azure B2C IDP pass through tokens

Tags: .net-core, oauth-2.0, blazor-webassembly, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-b2c

Using Microsoft Azure B2C with IDP pass through (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/idp-pass-through-user-flow?pivots=b2c-user-flow) in combination with a Blazor WASM application, I am having a problem where the Azure B2C jwt bearer is correctly refreshed post expiry however the inner idp claim has expired and is not renewed by Azure B2C. I am using the stock MSAL.

The "inner" idp has been provided by Microsoft Azure AD,  using the multi AD custom policy detailed here: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy)

My application integrates in a couple of places with Graph API to send emails from the logged on users Microsoft's 365 Mail account. This works great up until the "inner" token expires.

Even after this initial expiry generally my site works exactly as one would expect given MSAL handling the "outer" token refresh correctly.

However as soon as I call the endpoints in my app that use Idp token to send an email from a user it fails. (and crashes the site - I *think* this is because internally Graph API throws a ServiceException - but I haven't spent much more time on this - however Graph Api is the only Exception that brings down the site, and I can see container crashes being logged in the Azure portal)

Below is a sample of the code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace MyApp.Controllers
{


    [ApiController]
 
    public class SampleController : Controller
    {

        [HttpGet("/api/testsendmail")]

        public async Task<ActionResult> Send()
        {

            var user = HttpContext.User;
            var idpToken = user.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "idp_access_token")
                   .Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();

            
            if (idpToken != null)
            {

                var client = OnBehalfOfGraphClient.GetGraphClient(idpToken);


                var mail = client.Me.SendMail(new Message()
                {
                    ToRecipients = new Recipient[] {
                        new Recipient() {
                            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress() { Address = "test@nowhere.local" }
                        } },
                    Subject = "Test",
                    Body = new Microsoft.Graph.ItemBody() { ContentType = BodyType.Text, Content = "Test" },

                }, true).Request();

               // If the token specified in idpToken is invalid the following throws an IDP token exception, then crashes the site.
               // prior to the token expiring out this works as expected.
                var resp = await mail.PostResponseAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                
            }    

            return Ok();
        }




        public static class OnBehalfOfGraphClient
        {
            public static GraphServiceClient GetGraphClient(string token)
            {

                var authProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (request) =>
                {
                    request.Headers.Authorization =
                        new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                });

                var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

                return graphClient;

            }
        }


    }
}
```

In the short term I have "protected" the endpoints in my app that may experience this issue, by manually checking the idp token's expiry and sending a 403 response with a json problem detail body. At least this allows me to prompt the user to sign out and sign back in, however this is clearly sub optimal. (Ideally I'd like MSAL to handle the inner token being renewed or prompt the user to reauthenticate).

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Did you get a solution to this in the end?